# How to duplicate labels in a mailing label crystal report?

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I'm building a sales application in which the user can print the barcode of a product in a label, so I'm using visual studio WPF platfrom with crystal report to print the label, I succeded in displaying the barcode in a label from a barcode value with a specific formula, but I wonder how to duplicate this label, so say I would like to set the number of label in a variable, so it can duplicate the number of displayed labels.

```
DataRowView row = ArticleGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;// this is a datarow contained in a datagrid which has the barcode in the first column
CodeàBarre report = new CodeàBarre();// create new report
report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["barcode"].Text = "Generar_EAN13('"+row["Code à Barre"]+"')";//barcode is a formula field and Generar_EAN13 is the formula in crystal report that converts number into a barcode
TextObject désignation = report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Text2"] as TextObject;//this is a report textfield that contains product's name
TextObject prix = report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Text3"] as TextObject;//this is a report textfield that contains product's price
désignation.Text = row["Désignation"].ToString();// this is to assign the report textfield's value
prix.Text ="PU: "+row["Prix de Vente"].ToString()+" DA";// this is to assign the report textfield's value
```

Comment: Could you please clarify. You print just a barcode. This is in your detail band. You want (say) 6 of those rather than just one? The answer in that case is to add 6 numbers rather than one to whatever collection you present to the report.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the answer, you figured what I want to do,however, the issue with what you proposed is that I dont have a datasource for the report, I edited my answer for more code details.